# Null pointer Exception when processing XSD using xsom

Tags: java, xsd, nullpointerexception, xsom

i have an XSD like this

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="www.aaa.com/aa" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:include schemaLocation="class.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="record">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Stud" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="fname" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="lname" type="xs:string"/> 
                            ........                                
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

When i parse this XSD using XSOM it gives `Null Pointer Exception`. When i remove the `<xs:include schemaLocation="class.xsd"/>` element it works fine

```
 XSOMParser parser = new XSOMParser();
       parser.parse(inputStream);// -> this statement gives null pointer.
```

**Stack trace**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.NGCCRuntimeEx.parseEntity(NGCCRuntimeEx.java:327)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.NGCCRuntimeEx.includeSchema(NGCCRuntimeEx.java:234)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.includeDecl.action0(includeDecl.java:42)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.includeDecl.leaveElement(includeDecl.java:109)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.state.NGCCRuntime.endElement(NGCCRuntime.java:275)
    at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.endElement(XMLFilterImpl.java:546)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.parse(XMLFilterImpl.java:333)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.parser.JAXPParser.parse(JAXPParser.java:115)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.NGCCRuntimeEx.parseEntity(NGCCRuntimeEx.java:337)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.ParserContext.parse(ParserContext.java:124)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.parser.XSOMParser.parse(XSOMParser.java:183)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.parser.XSOMParser.parse(XSOMParser.java:138)
```

thanks in advance

Comment: try parsing `class.xsd` alone.

Comment: i parsed the 'class.xsd' using same lib, it works fine

Comment: http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/com/sun/xml/internal/xsom/impl/parser/NGCCRuntimeEx.java.html ... here you can find source code for `NGCCRuntimeEx` class. see if you can debug it.

Comment: do you know any other java XSD processor

Comment: I guess your class.xsd must be in the correct location if you want the parser to find it. The errormessage should have been better though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Why NullPointerException occurs**
The problem is that there is no error handler to handle the exception thrown while parsing and hence an exception in parsing causes returning of null.

Setting the instance of an implementation of `org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler` as errorHandler solves  the issue.

```
parser.setErrorHandler(new DOMErrorHandler());
```

`DOMErrorHandler` is the implementation of org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler.

**Why xs:include doesn't work**

The parser parses the `InputStream` of the specified `XSD`. So it won't get the `systemId()` of given schema, using which a baseURI has to be created for accessing included files. Thus it won't be able to access the file to be included.

So when i call `parser.parse()` with `InputSource` of the schema, it works fine.